# Error 'OSError: libtiepie.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory' when trying to import module in Python

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. However, the same error occurs if I try to run the code from the terminal or using Spyder. I need to import a module called libtiepie which I installed in the virtual environment using the terminal tab on Pycharm. The installation was successful, and the folder with the proper files appeared in /PycharmProjects/tiepie/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libtiepie (and it is listed in the tab Python Packages). But everytime I try to import the module using `import libtiepie` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/315/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/315/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tandeitnik/PycharmProjects/tiepie/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libtiepie/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .api import api
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/315/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tandeitnik/PycharmProjects/tiepie/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libtiepie/api.py", line 1020, in <module>
    api = load_libtiepie()
  File "/home/tandeitnik/PycharmProjects/tiepie/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libtiepie/api.py", line 14, in load_libtiepie
    api = CDLL(DLL_PATH)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libtiepie.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Go to the end of the docs in the [**troubleshooting** section](https://www.tiepie.com/en/libtiepie-sdk/python), notice your error is explained there... The solution is: *"To avoid that, make sure `libtiepie.so` doesn't exist in the script's directory."* So if the file exists inside the scripts folder of the venv delete it, that should fix the problem.

Comment: I looked in the venv directory (and other directories) for the `libtiepie.so` using the terminal (to check if it was hidden) and didn't find it. I don't think this is the problem since the traceback described in the troubleshooting section you mentioned is quite different from the traceback error I am getting.

Comment: Your venv looks a bit strange to me, in the last line it seems Python is looking in the Python base installation path. Did you activate the right venv before installing and running from it?

Comment: I believe I did because on the terminal (which I used to install the module) it is written `(venv) tandeitnik@tandeitnik:~/PycharmProjects/tiepie`. Indeed it is strange that on the last line, it looks inside `/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/`, but on the other lines it looks on the right folder inside the environment. One detail, if I install another module, like numpy, I can import it successfully.